# Python Tornado server with WebSockets: Allow concurrency across websockets but doing things sequentially in the same websocket

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, yield, coroutine

Is there a way to run all messages that arrive to the same websocket sequentially, in a blocking way, while without blocking messages arriving to different websocket?

So let's assume someone is using `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 8 threads (to utilize all available cores), together with the `yield` statement and the `@gen.coroutine` decorator, every time the server runs `executor.submit` the task goes to some thread arbitrarily. I'd like to enforce that for a given WebSocket, only one thread will handle the tasks, in order to assure things will run sequentially.

Comment: I think the simplest possible solution would be to create a separate `executor` specifically for that Websocket with only 1 worker. That will result in only one thread and the things will be sequential.

Comment: @xyres but the problem is that you will not have a limit on the number of threads, and the reason to use ThreadPoolExecutor is to limit the number of threads.